# TestManager's Testing Center has a "Test Results" report I'd like to open in VS

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

TestManager's Testing Center has a "Test Results" report I'd like to open in VS. I'd like to download it and add it to my TFS's SSRS, is this possible? Is there a link to where I can get the report from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the Results screen in MTM with the pie charts and bar charts.  That's not a report per se, but just a screen within the MTM client.  There is no equivalent SSRS report out of the box (just Test Case Readiness, Test Plan Progress, and Stories Overview).  Of course you're always free to create you're own.

You can also add Test Results charts in the TFS Web Portal.